# Does Rift Herald change Baron?

Tags: league-of-legends

Since the latest patch, they've introduced the 'Rift Herald' that spawns before Baron. I'm a support main so I'm rarely in top jungle, and usually the top lane takes it anyway. What exactly does killing it grant, and does it influence Baron at all? In addition, do whatever buffs it grants only apply to whoever kills it?

Comment: It does not influence Baron at all. It will despawn at 19:45 if it's out of combat, or 19:55 unconditionally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although some of these points are addressed in the other answer, the question leads me to think that he is wondering about the baron/rift herald interaction and possibly the interaction between the buffs granted, as it is possible to take baron while having rift herald buff, so I have compiled all info I can find on the Rift Herald.

As of patch [7.9](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-79-notes),

After killing the Rift Herald, you may pick up the relic left behind, which will grant you the "Eye of the Void" which temporarily replaces their trinket.

This grants Empowered Recall when held, and allows for summoning of the Rift Herald after a 3.5 second charge time.

**Note:** Lasts for 4 minutes (or until used) and is retained even if slain, and can be held even if you have baron buff, though you do not get a doubly Empowered Recall.  Also, if Rift Herald has not been killed at 19:45 it will immediately return to the void(despawn) if not in combat. If in combat, it will despawn at 19:55 after it is killed, or despawns, it will not return for the rest of the game.

Comment: +1 for updating it yet again after the patches, despite this being an old answer.

Comment: @ChronoD thanks. just realized today that this was horribly out of date with the huge mid season patch. though the balances in 6.10 with likely invalidate most of this again.

Comment: How are the corruption charges gained? I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: @Calculemus sorry for the late reply. Just updated the info for that. It charges as current level/18 charges per second.

Comment: You might also want to add that Rift Herald does not replace Baron on the map. If he hasn't already been killed, he will despawn automatically 15 seconds before Baron spawns.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Rift Herald](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rift_Herald),

> Slaying the Rift Herald grants the slayer the [Doom's Eve buff](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Doom's_Eve).

The buff gives movement speed, increased damage, improved recall and the minion aura.

It's a tuned down [Hand of Baron](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hand_of_Baron) buff basically. Only the killer gets it and the bonuses are lessen (except movement speed which Baron does not provide).